# Angular ng-swipe prevent on children

Tags: angularjs, swipe, children

How can I prevent default on child element?

I have content element:

```
<div id="content" class="full" ng-swipe-right="openSwipeNav(allowSwipe); swiping = true" ng-swipe-left="closeSwipeNav(allowSwipe); swiping = true" ng-mouseup="closeNav($event)" ng-click="swiping=false;">
```

Inside this #content is:

```
<input type="range">
```

But it's not working. I can move range slider just a little bit and of course it trigger opening navigation. When I remove ng-swipe-right & ng-swipe-left it works ok.

I tried this solution: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yve2rLkr/6/)

But it still didn't work for range input...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There can be couple of different ways in which you can achieve this.

Keep in mind that the same swipe event is being caught by both the slider and the content. Also, because the slider is a child of content, when you slide it, the event is first received by the slider and then bubbled up to the content. So you can stop the event's propagation inside the handler for slider's swipe.

Or, if you want to be more verbose about it, catch the event in the content's swipe-left handler function, check it's target and confirm that it doesn't contain the slider element as it's target.

Maybe create a directive called something like 'disableSwipe' which bind to touch events and prevents their propagation, to the range element.

```
myApp.directive('disableSwipe', function(){
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var disableSwipeListener = function(event) {
          console.log('mm')
          event.stopPropagation();
      }
      $(element).on("mousedown", disableSwipeListener);
      $(element).on("mousemove", disableSwipeListener);
      $(element).on("mouseup", disableSwipeListener);
    }
  }
})
```

Heres a quick and dirty fiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/yve2rLkr/25/

Comment: Davesh in my case it's not working. I see that your solution works in jsfiddle. Maybe there is problem that in my #content I have view so input range is defined in view... I can move slider just a little bit but if I make bigger swipe it opens navigation. Even logs are not called

Comment: It's strange because when I remove ng-swipe-right & ng-swipe-left from #content it works. But when I remove only functions it's not working